# how to stop triggering onMouseDown when element is only clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to develop a game in which units(svg elms) are moved with react

The unit should be move by dragging. A form should be open if its only clicked.
When I click the unit mousedown is triggerd but onclick is not.

```
class Unit extends Component {
  state = {
     moving:false
  };
  handleClick = (e) =>{
    console.log("Clicked");
  }
  startMove = e => {
    this.setState({moving:true})
  };
  render() {
    return (
          <g className="u-wrapper">
          <g onClick={this.handleClick}
          onMouseDown={this.startMove}>
          {this.createCircle()}
          />
        </g>
        {this.renderRangeCircle()};
      </g>
    );
  }
}
```

mouseDown should not trigger if mouse is only clicked.
may be way to trigger both but onclick first

Comment: Don't use `onClick`, use `mouseDown` to set `moving: true` (as you are), `mouseUp` to set `moving: false` and `onMouseMove` to track dragging movement when `moving`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to prevent the `mousedown` event from firing like that, because the [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) event will always fire last. It is triggered by the mouse button being pressed and then released, so obviously you will first always have a `mousedown` event in a situation where `click` would be fired.

This is explained in the docs:

> The click event fires when a pointing device button (e.g., a mouse's
>   primary button) is pressed and released on a single element. If the
>   button is pressed on one element and released on a different one, the
>   event is fired on the most specific ancestor element that contained
>   both.
>
> *click fires **after** the mousedown and mouseup events, in that order.*